# Update a python dictionary based on a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a for loop running over permutations of a list of elements `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`. Here is what I want the code to do:

```
[inside the for loop over permutations]

perm = ['a', 'c', 'd']
val = [1, 2, 3] 

myDict = dict(zip(perm, val))

-- next iteration --

perm = ['a', 'd', 'f']
val = [2, 1, 6]
```

now I want `myDict` to add the values of the keys it already contains and simply insert the ones it does not, so the result should be:

```
myDict = {'a' : 1+2, 'c' : 2, 'd' : 3+6, 'f' : 6}
```

and so on for the entire loop. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = defaultdict(int)

[inside the for loop over permutations]

for k, v in zip(perm, val):
    myDict[k] += v
```